# Hybris. Export data. Passing incorrect impexscript to Exporter

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I'm unable to export impexscript due to error:

```
de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExException: line 3 at main script: No valid line type found for {0=, 1=user_to_test_export}
```

This is how I'm doing export of my data using impex

```
   String impexScript = String.format("INSERT Customer;uid[unique=true];\n" + 
                                                        ";%s", customer.getUid());

   ImpExMedia impExMedia = ImpExManager.getInstance().createImpExMedia("test_importexport_exportscript");
   impExMedia.setData(new ByteArrayInputStream(impexScript.getBytes()), "CustomerData", "text/csv");

   ExportConfiguration config = new ExportConfiguration(impExMedia, ImpExManager.getExportOnlyMode());
   Exporter exporter = new Exporter(config);
   exporter.export();
```

Comment: Please add this method definition as well--> generateImpExScriptForCustomer.

Comment: My bad, I was passing impExMedia straight, can you check my code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User/Customer can be easily exported via groovy.

```
  import de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.*
  import de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.exp.ExportConfiguration
  import de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.exp.Exporter
  import de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.exp.Export


    String impexScript = String.format("INSERT Customer;uid[unique=true]");

    ImpExMedia impExMedia = ImpExManager.getInstance().createImpExMedia("test_importexport_exportscript");
    impExMedia.setData(new ByteArrayInputStream(impexScript.getBytes()), "CustomerData", "text/csv");

    ExportConfiguration config = new ExportConfiguration(impExMedia, ImpExManager.getExportOnlyMode());
    Exporter exporter = new Exporter(config);
    Export export = exporter.export();
    println(export.getExportedData())
```

**Note: run groovy in commit mode.**

Sample Output:
data_export_1676281713548(data_export_1676281713548(8798244438046))
With this PK `8798244438046` ImpExMedia can be search easily in Backoffice.